# ALFA to XACML plugin

Tags: xacml, abac, alfa

The Alfa language submitted to OASIS by Axiomatics looks quite nice. However I wonder whether there is any free compiler from Alfa to XACML. The license file which comes with the Axiomatics Eclipse plugin states it is for non-commercial / evaluation. And it is not integrated with Maven etc. Is there some free alternative?

Comment: Hi David, is the plugin actually for non-commercial purpose only? It is stated as FREE on the download page but has license file included stating different

Comment: It is for non commercial use only. You can use it for academia for free.

Comment: If you decide to become a customer of Axiomatics, you can get a version of the plugin that allows the policies developed with it to be used for commercial purpose. If not, the free plugin available restricts the policies created to be deployed only in non-commercial environments.